# Update only Top 1 OR anyone row of a table using join with another table

Tags: sql-server

I want to Update only top 1 OR only 1 row of a column where a column values are same.
(Just logical explanation don't go on syntax)
LIKE:
Update [Total] = (value from a another table with a common column)
but need to update only top 1 row OR any one row to the current (updating) table not all rows matching column value...

e.g
Table 1:

```
Skill      Value
 abc        3    
 def        4
 xyz        3.5
```

Table 2:

```
Name    Skill   MyValue MyValue2(ColumnNeedsToBeUpdated)
Ram      abc       3      
shyam    abc       4
Mohan    abc       5
Raju     xyz       4
Ratan    xyz       6
```

Now I want to Update `MyValue2` based on `Table1` column `Skill` `Value` = `MyValue2` but I want to update anyone OR top 1 row in `Table2` **NOT ALL** Please help

Expected Output:

```
Name    Skill   MyValue MyValue2(ColumnNeedsToBeUpdated)
Ram      abc       3      3
shyam    abc       4      
Mohan    abc       5       
Raju     xyz       4      3.5
Ratan    xyz       6
```

OR Alternate output can be:

```
Name    Skill                    MyValue MyValue2(ColumnNeedsToBeUpdated)
Ram      abc       3        Value from Table1 / no. of records with skill abc   (3/3)  
shyam    abc       4
Mohan    abc       5
Raju     xyz       4        Value from Table1 / no. of records with skill xyz   (3.5/2)
Ratan    xyz       6
```

Comment: Top 1 means, based on which column it has to sort? Add your expected output also

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: add a column in table one as myvalue2 and put that value in it.

Comment: Thanks all for down voting this question with out any reason... You guys can answer as this is not possible and I need to find some alternative...

Comment: @Abhinav I did but it updated all the rows for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Table 2`, give a row number based on group by `Skill` column and order by `MyValue` column. And then updated the rows which having row number`1` with `Value` from `Table 1`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by Skill
        order by [MyValue]
    ), *
    from [Table2]
)
update t1
set t1.[MyValue2] = t2.[Value]
from cte t1
join [Table1] t2
on t1.[Skill] = t2.[Skill]
where t1.[rn] = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks bro you did it... It worked but not with float value which I know why I will handle it...But you did what I requested. Thanks a lot for that

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't resolve with float values can u help ?

Comment: @NikhilPatel : What is the datatype for `MyValue2` column in `Table2`?

Comment: its a temp table without any predefined structure... should define it with decimal(10,2)  OR Float ?

Comment: I defined it and it worked.. Thanks again :) you made my day :D